# Credenciais confiáveis com Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Tenho um sistema web no qual captura o id do usuário do Facebook e armazena ele no banco de dados para uso posterior, atualmente faço a chamada via o SDK e o mando por campo oculto(método de pouca segurança).

Gostaria de saber se posso inserir esta informação (o id) de alguma forma mais segura?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma recomendada é seguir o [flow de autenticação](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/) definido pelo Facebook, assim eles garantem a "forma segura". Mas imagino que você esteja efetuando a autenticação com a api do Facebook no front, pegando os dados do usuário(id) e enviando para o servidor.

Uma outra forma de fazer isso seria enviar um request (**Https obrigatório**) passando o accessToken que você obteve no front, e no backend revalidar esse token e pegar os dados do usuário através da api novamente.